# UglifyJS inline script instead of filename

Tags: javascript, uglifyjs

I'm wondering how I can compress an inline script with UglifyJS from the command line.

All the examples everywhere show file names, i.e.

```
uglifyjs somefile.js -o somefile.min.js
```

What I want to do is:

```
uglifyjs -option "function hello(){ var world='world'; alert(world) }"
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use what is known as "heredocs" or "herestrings" (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document). This technique works with just about any program that takes a file as an argument (in this case the shell is piping the string for you onto stdin). Should work on most shells / OSes.

As a herestring:

```
uglifyjs <<<"function hello(){ var world='world'; alert(world) }"
```

or, as a heredoc:

```
uglifyjs <<_END_
function hello() {
  var world='world';
  alert(world)
}
_END_
```

Comment: Remember, you can also pipe the output of one tool to the input of another, for example: `gzcat source.js.gz | uglifyjs -m -c | gzip > source.min.js.gz` This takes a compressed (with gzip) JavaScript source file, decompresses it, minifies it, compresses that, then saves it to a file. As this is a pipe, it is more efficient than multiple disk file open/close/unlinks.

Answer (score 1):

You can always use temporary files:

`echo "function hello(){ var world='world'; alert(world) }" > tmp.js; uglifyjs tmp.js -o tmp.min.js; cat tmp.min.js; rm -f tmp.js tmp.out.js`